# What does PER PORTAM CAPENAM ROMAM mean in this sentence?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

> Is quī viā Latīnā venit per portam Capēnam Rōmam intrat.

Since it's all Accusative, I'm having a hard time figuring out what it means.

I'm guessing it might mean something like

> He who comes from the Latin path/road enters through the ** *door ... Capena ... Rome*? **

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that *intrō* takes an accusative, and *per* also takes an accusative.

Since there are multiple accusatives next to each other, by default, I'd assign each one to the nearest "accusative-taker":

> Is quī viā Latīnā venit [per portam Capēnam] [Rōmam intrat].
> *He who comes from the Via Latina [enters Rome] [through the Porta Capena].*

And indeed, this default interpretation seems to make sense, since [the *porta Capēna* is the name of an actual gate in the walls of Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porta_Capena).

Another clue comes from the fact that prepositions tend to come before their nouns—hence the name—and verbs tend to come after. It's not a hard-and-fast law, especially in poetry, but it's a good rule of thumb to keep in mind.

Comment: Also, the *Via Latina* was the name of an important Roman road leading (approximately) east for 200km from Rome. However the Porta Capena area of Rome had become run-down and was demolished and rebuilt in the 2nd century, and the location was renamed the *Porta Appia*, which was the starting point of a different road, the Appian Way, connecting Rome to the coast at what is now Naples